# Powershell command to retrieve storage account resource id, blob resourceid from Storage account V2

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell

I want to retrieve all components resource id from Storage account using powershell command.

- Storage Account Resource ID
- Blob service-Resource ID
- File service-Resource ID
- Queue service-Resource ID
- Table service-Resource ID

I tried with below command for blob service, but resource id is not available in the property

```
Get-AzStorageBlobServiceProperty -ResourceGroupName "rg-eval" -AccountName "dlseval"
```

How can I retrieve the Resource Id's dynamically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no direct way to get all the ID that you are looking for, but once you get `Storage Account Resource ID`, you can combine other service ID yourself, they are fixed, just try the code below:

```
$account = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName '<Group Namw>' -Name '<account Name>' 

$accountResID = $account.ID
$blobResID = $account.ID + "/blobServices/default"
$fileResID = $account.ID + "/fileServices/default"
$queueResID = $account.ID + "/queueServices/default"
$tableResID = $account.ID + "/tableServices/default"
```